# Using Sencha's app.json to manage Javascript load order and dependencies

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

Sencha Touch uses a Microloader to manage the assembly and loading of Javascript files.

My problem is that I have yet to find a good resource that fully explains all of the options and how they affect the order in which the Javascript files are processed, loaded and run.

This needs to be understood so a developer can properly manage the JS dependencies, including when Ext.define() is available, and when to load the overrides.

The resource Sencha provides: http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/microloader.html, touches on a couple of the options but not all, and it does not discuss how this affects the order in which the Javascript runs.

A typical js: section might look as follows:

```
   "js": [
      {
         "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js",
         "x-bootstrap": true
      },
      {
         "path": "bootstrap.js",
         "x-bootstrap": true
      },
      {
         "path": "overrides.js",
         "x-bootstrap": true
      },
      {
         "path": "library1.js",
         "includeInBundle": true
      },
      {
         "path": "library2.js",
         "remote": true
      },
      {
         "path": "library3.js"
      },
      {
         "path": "library4.js",
         "x-bootstrap": true
      },
      {
         "path": "app.js",
         "bundle": true,
         "update": "delta"
      }
```

The options that affect the load order that I am aware of are:

- x-bootstrap,
- remote,
- includeInBundle,
- bundle  /* Final Entry Point, all bundled js included here. */

In addition there is the order of the files in the list.

So my question is...   The JS files "library1.js", "library2.js", "library3.js", "library4.js".    What order will they be processed, loaded and run, and why....

As part of this question:

- When would the dependency Ext.define() be ready?
- When/how should overrides be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

From what I’ve gathered you want Sencha/bootstrap to be your first two entries and you want app.js to be your last entry. You want app.js last since it’s where all the bundled entries end up. As for bootstrap, I think I’ve removed all the entries for it aside from bootstrap.js due to loading order changing depending on if it's run from a built app or not (From what I’ve been able to glean from the internet and my own testing).

I myself load all Ext components into the bundle and have the  overrides load last.

So from what little I know about this the loading order when debugging would be:

1. touch/sencha-touch.js
2. bootstrap.js
3. overrides.js
4. library1.js
5. library2.js
6. library3.js
7. library4.js
8. app.js

When running from a build I believe it would be the following:

1. bootstrap.js

   1. touch/sencha-touch.js
   2. overrides.js
   3. library4.js
2. library2.js
3. library3.js
4. app.js

   1. library1.js

From what I understand the remote tag doesn't actually change load order, it just means that the build doesn't copy the script over. You'd usually use that for loading remote libraries (ie: scripts on another server) or for when you manage the copying of the scripts over yourself.